# Can I export a VM image from google cloud engine and open with Virtualbox or VMware?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtualbox, google-compute-engine, vmware

I have a VM in google cloud platform, and I want to download it and open in virtualbox or VMware in my local machine.

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow this instructions:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image

You can convert raw file generated with VirtualBox Manage tool:

```
VBoxManage convertdd sdb.raw sdb.vdi --format VDI
```